# From which page the current page is loaded?

Tags: javascript

I have three html pages audit.html,section.html and questions.html. Now, in audit.html, when user clicks on link that points to section.html, i want to know in section.html(Please tell javascript code) from which page the section.html page is called?(in this case current page section.html is called from audit.html).

Please tell me javascript code to know from which html page the current html page is loaded?

Answer (score 4):

Using JavaScript you can use something called:

```
document.referrer
```

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer):

> Returns the URI of the page that linked to this page.

Also note:

> The value is an empty string if the user navigated to the page directly (not through a link, but, for example, via a bookmark). Since this property returns only a string, it does not give you DOM access to the referring page.

**Check the fiddle here:** http://plnkr.co/edit/1jFHk9Hjjm0StTQRbTIe?p=preview

I have created three files: `section.html`, `audit.html`, and `index.html`. All are displaying their referrer using the code:

```
document.getElementById("ref").innerHTML = document.referrer;
```